# Psychtoolbox - Text for Instruction

Tags: matlab, drawtext, psychtoolbox

I have some problems using Psychtoolbox Screen and Textwindow...
For my experiment I want to give an instruction at the beginning. I used something like this:
% Draw text in the middle of the screen in Courier in white

```
Screen('TextSize', window, 20);
Screen('TextFont', window, 'Courier');
DrawFormattedText(window, 'Hello World', 'center', 'center', white);
```

And the other basic Screen definitions.
The problem is: The text is not fully shown. I tried different sizes and set the Font to Times, but it is always the same - every letter is only displayed 3/4 (ca)...

What could be the problem?
Would be very nice if someone can give me a hint...

Thanks!

[image: Letters are cut]

Answer (score 1):

Can you describe what you mean by 'every letter is only displayed 3/4 (ca)"? The code you posted looks correct. For example, here is that code, with the addition of some set-up routines, and taking and saving a screenshot as "testImage.png", with the screen shot attached.

```
screenNum = max(Screen('Screens'));
window = Screen('OpenWindow', screenNum, 0);
white = WhiteIndex(window);
Screen('TextSize', window, 20);
Screen('TextFont', window, 'Courier');
DrawFormattedText(window, 'Hello World', 'center', 'center', white)
Screen('Flip', window);
imageArray = Screen('GetImage', window);
WaitSecs(3);
Screen('CloseAll');
imwrite(imageArray, 'testImage.png');
```

[image: screen shot of screen produced by the above code]

Comment: Hey DMR, thank you for your answer! I edited my post, hope you can see what I mean...
I've tried your code in an extra script and it worked fine. So I guess it has to do with my experimental loop or something, but I can't imagine what could be the problem... Maybe I should note that I have 
    KbWait([],2);
after the code above, because I want to continue the experimental loop when the proband has read the instruction and presses a key

Comment: Do you have any other statements between your 'DrawFormattedText' and the next Screen 'Flip' command? Subsequent drawing commands would overlap on top of each other.

Comment: No, this is my full code for this section:
 % Draw text in the upper portion of the screen with the default font in black
    Screen('FillRect', window, white);
    Screen('BlendFunction', window, 'GL_SRC_ALPHA', 'GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA');
    Screen('TextSize', window, 10);
    Screen('TextFont', window, 'Times');
    DrawFormattedText(window, 'Press the Enter Key if you are ready', 'center', 'center', black);
    %screenYpixels * 0.25, [0 0 0]);
    Screen('Flip', window); % show what was drawed
    KbWait([],2);

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... Just a dumb mistake in my long Code. I have set the Font and Size of Text earlier, and this interfered with this new text features. Nevertheless, thank you for your help!